# vim fugitive - stage all files matching pattern

Tags: plugin-fugitive

I am trying to stage all files matching a pattern from the fugitive status window (`:G`).

I tried something like `:g/<pattern>/:normal s` but for some reason, only the first matching file is staged. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Probably the issue is that things get moved around in the buffer. You could probably do something like `:G add glob` as a workaround.